# Is there a "clean" solution for the "Object Manager has been closed" error (JPA)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using JPA (not JDO) on Google App Engine and this is a typical example of my service method:

```
@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public Collection<Message> getAll() {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Collection<Message> result = null;

    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Message e");
        result =  query.getResultList();
        //The workaround
        //if(result != null) result.size();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I try to use the collection outside the method I get the "famous" error reporting that the object manager is closed. Calling the size() method is a workaround, but I dislike this kind of "dirty" solution. I wonder there isn't any method to have this collection detached or lazy loading disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is "clean", but a frequently recommended approach is to have a servlet filter that creates a thread-local EntityManager before your code runs and closes it at the very end.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. Since I use Springframework instead of thread-local it should be a request-scope bean.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring (as you appear to), the [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/) is the "proper" way to expose the EntityManager to the views, thus allowing persistent collections to be lazily fetched in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Use v2 of the GAE JPA plugin; can't get much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Use the Guice JPA plugin, can't get much simpler than that.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA